# Acessing data from multiple tables (SQL) in one php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi im new in php/sql programing, im making a website in html and whem i enter the fields on texbox i could pass the data to mysql database.

html example:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="get">
<TABLE>

<TR>
<TH style="width: 454px">

<select name="marcas">
<option value ="1"> Peugeot   </option>
<option value = "2"> Renault  </option>
<option value ="3"> Opel </option>
</select>
<select name="modelo">
<option value ="1"> 105   </option>
<option value = "2"> 205  </option>
<option value ="3"> 507 </option>
</select>
<P align="left">Matricula: <INPUT NAME="matricula" TYPE=text SIZE="20">
<P align="left">Ano: <INPUT NAME="ano" TYPE=text SIZE="60">
<p align="left">Quilometros: <INPUT NAME="kms" TYPE=text SIZE="20"> 
<tr><td>Estado:</td><td>
<input type="radio" name="estado"value="usado">Usado<br>
<input type="radio" name="estado" value="novo">Novo
</td></tr>  

</TH>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Now i got PHP to connect to table cars:

```
<?php
  include "connect.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO carro (id_modelo, id_cor,id_extras, matricula, ano, kms,    estado) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$_REQUEST["id_modelo"],$_REQUEST["id_cor"],$_REQUEST["id_extras"], $_REQUEST["matricula"], $_REQUEST["ano"], $_REQUEST["kms"], $_REQUEST["estado"]);

$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->affected_rows == -1) {
  echo "<p>". $mysqli->error. "</p>";
}
else {
  echo "<sp>Carro Inserido com Sucesso!</p>";
}

$stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

My question is , i want that some of the fields in textbox connect with other diferent table but i dont know if thats possible, for example something like:

```
$sql = INSERT INTO car
$sql2 = INSERT INTO engine
$sql3 = INSERT INTO brand
```

some code that can make me in the same page enter the data for diferent tables

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track already, although you cannot insert into different tables in a single `INSERT INTO` query.

Instead all you need to do is perform three separate `INSERT INTO` queries, i.e. one for each table.

In each query just use the value from your `$_REQUEST` data that you need. For example once you've done your query to add data to your Cars table you would just perform another query for e.g. Engine like:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO Engines (** Columns **) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param(...);

$stmt->execute();

...

}
```

and bind the inputs you want like you did before. All you'll need to do is add extra `input` fields to your form to get the extra data you want.